# Accessing an element from a table created dynamically with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Good morning!

I need to access the information of an item that is in a table. More precisely, I need to click on it to open another window, but the table where this element is located is created dynamically.
CSS Selector :

#**mCSB_3**_container > div.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(7)

Element xpatch:
//*[@id="**mCSB_3**_container"]/div [1]/table/tbody/tr [1]/td [1]

Today I trying to get the element with this way :

```
        PegaMscb = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class=mCSB_container"))
        PegaMscbID = PegaMscb[1].get_attribute("id")
```

The problem with this Way is I aways get one fixed element with name mCSB_1.

My question is that mCSB_3 every moment is a number... it can be 43, 40, 6...etc.

There is any way I put in find element that the class =mCSB_container but the id is diferente  from mCSB_1?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: can you confirm the url?

Comment: It is a private system, but the URL displayed in the browser is a different path that shows the tables I want to click on. For example, the URL shows www.site.com/kpi ... then I click on it and it shows a table with multiple rows... but the URL is still the same www.site.com/kpi and when I click on it, only a popup window is displayed

Comment: this part `mCSB_` and `_container ` are static, but the number that comes in between is dynamic right?

Comment: Exactly!!!  And I only know the element I need is diferent from 1

Comment: Try find that container using the following command:`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'mCSB_') and contains(@id, '_container')]"`. You need to import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: Hi, I got the following error: 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "xpath", "selector":"//*[starts-with(@id, 'mCSB_') and contains(@id, '_container"]/div [1]/table/tbody/')]"}' . But when I look at inspect, the table exists with this xpath : '//*[@id="mCSB_9_container"]/div [1]/table/tbody/tr [1]/td [1]' . I do not know, I thought maybe the table is in a different frame, but I do  not know how to find out the exact frame.